# Confused Case Statement Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select
    -----
    date_tbl.[Date Name]
    -----
    ,case
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 1 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 1 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 1 Start')
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 1 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 31 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 1 End')
        -----
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 2 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 1 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 2 Start')
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 2 and (day(eomonth(date_tbl.[Date Name])) = 28 OR day(eomonth(date_tbl.[Date Name])) = 29) then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 2 End')
        -----
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 3 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 1 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 3 Start')
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 3 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 31 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 3 End')
        -----
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 4 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 1 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 4 Start')
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 4 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 30 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 4 End')
        -----
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 5 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 1 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 5 Start')
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 5 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 31 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 5 End')
        -----
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 6 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 1 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 6 Start')
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 6 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 30 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 6 End')
        -----
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 7 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 1 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 7 Start')
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 7 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 31 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 7 End')
        -----
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 8 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 1 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 8 Start')
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 8 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 31 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 8 End')
        -----
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 9 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 1 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 9 Start')
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 9 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 30 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 9 End')
        -----
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 10 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 1 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 10 Start')
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 10 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 31 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 10 End')
        -----
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 11 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 1 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 11 Start')
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 11 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 30 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 11 End')
        -----
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 12 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 1 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 12 Start')
        when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 12 and day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 31 then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 12 End')
        -----
        else NULL
        end as [month_label]
    -----
from
    [dbo].[DATES] as date_tbl
```

My results look like this:

```
Date Name     month_label
1900-01-01    1900 - Month 1 Start
1900-01-02    NULL
...           ...
1900-01-31    1900 - Month 1 End
1900-02-01    1900 - Month 2 Start
1900-02-02    1900 - Month 2 End
1900-02-03    1900 - Month 2 End
1900-02-04    1900 - Month 2 End
1900-02-28    1900 - Month 2 End
1900-03-01    1900 - Month 3 Start
1900-03-02    NULL
.....         .....
1900-03-31    1900 - Month 3 End
```

Why does my February labels have the "end" value for every row instead of the last day of the month? How do I fix it so that it only labels the 1st and last days of each month?

Comment: won't day of eomonth always evaluate either to 28 or 29 which in turn will append that 'end'? What is the purpose of using eomonth only for Feb in your case?

Comment: To account for Leap Year values. Sometimes the last day of February is the 28th, sometimes it's the 29th depending on whether or not the year is a leap year.

Comment: There is an answer below from Dhruv which solutions this I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you have eomonth function in your february case statement.
The EOMONTH function gives last of the month for any date. So all dates satisfy the last date case statement.

you need to change the below line

```
when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 2 and (day(eomonth(date_tbl.[Date Name])) = 28 OR day(eomonth(date_tbl.[Date Name])) = 29) then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 2 End')
```

to

```
    when month(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 2 and (day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 28 OR day(date_tbl.[Date Name]) = 29) then concat(cast(year(date_tbl.[Date Name]) as varchar(255)),' - ','Month 2 End')
```

Comment: Ah, I should have thought about it more. Your solution works, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need all those `CASE` expression for every month.

Just check for `DAY (DateCol) = 1` for first of the month and `DateCol = EOMONTH(DateCol)` for end of the month date

```
CONCAT(DATENAME(year, [DateCol ]),
       ' - Month ',
       month([DateCol ]),
       case when day([DateCol ]) = 1             then ' Start'
            when [DateCol] = EOMONTH([DateCol ]) then ' End'
            end) as [month_label]
```